# Umlaut-problems (UTF-8) only on first page load

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, diacritics

I have a php/mysql-application on a plesk-server with Apache and nginx. I have the strange problem that only when the browser is opened and the website is accessed for the first time in that browser-session, Umlaute (special characters) like the german ä ö ü are displayed as "?". As soon as I refresh the site, it won't happen again until I close and re-open the browser.

Everything from DB over PHP to HTML is UTF-8 encoded.

Any hints what I should look for?

I noticed that when deleting the cookies, closing and opening the browser, it does NOT happen.

I noticed the problems only happen with content coming from the (entirely UTF-8-encoded) MySql-DB and only when I'm logged in... very strange!

**Solution**

Ok, I'm not the person that silently goes away when I was just too dump to find my fault! So, hopefully my error will help someone else in the future:

I had a PDO-connection that only happens when a user was logged in, but his session timed out. This query logs the user in based on a cookie. On that SQL-connection, I had only:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

instead of

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

As it seems, this was the whole error!

Comment: It may be related to HTTP header: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` When you are accessing the site for the 1-st time charset is not set. For the 2-nd time it is set.

Comment: that is true, I have that line in my first-called php-file. What can I change? Is it a server-config-issue?